# How can I update different column values of the same table with multiple conditions?

Tags: sql-server

I am working with SQL Server 2014. I am new to SQL Server development and working on client's requirement. I need help with one report...

This is my table `LOANS`:

```
  pid   c_name   ProductFlag  Duration   Discription
=====================================================
1.    Ash       p           Annual     Vehicle loan
2.    JOHN     GOLD          Half       Gold Loan
3.    Prit     Home          Annual     Home loan 
4.    Pari      P            Half       Vehicle loan
5.    Stacy    Home          Annual     Home loan 
6.    Meet     Gold          Annual     Gold Loan
7.    Mandy    Gold          Quarterly   Gold Loan
8.    Rose     Home          Annual      Home loan  
9.    Rita    Tractor         Half       Tractor loan  
10.    Lary   Education       Half        Education loan
```

I want to update column `Description` based on `Productflag` values as

```
update LOANS 
set description = CASE  
                     WHEN productflag = 'p' THEN 'applied for vehicle loan '
                     WHEN productflag = 'gold' THEN 'applied for gold loan'
```

and at same time I want to update column `description` based on `Duration` values.

No matter what the `Productflag` is, for that particular duration ....(except productflags 'p' and 'gold' which I want to update as mentioned above )

I just want to update column `Description` based on `Duration` values as follows:

```
update LOANS 
set description = CASE  
                     WHEN Duration = 'half' THEN 'applied for half year'
                     WHEN Duration = 'Quarter' THEN 'applied for Quarter year loan'
```

Following should be the output

```
 pid   c_name   ProductFlag  Duration   Discription
=====================================================
1.    Ash       p           Annual     applied for vehicle loan
2.    JOHN     GOLD          Half      applied for half year
3.    Prit     Home          Annual     Home loan 
4.    Pari      P            Half       applied for half year
5.    Stacy    Home          Annual    Home loan 
6.    Meet     Gold          Annual     applied for gold loan
7.    Mandy    Gold          Quarterly  applied for Quarter year loan
8.    Rose     Home          Annual      Home loan  
9.    Rita    Tractor         Half      applied for half year
10.    Lary   Education       Half       applied for half year
```

Please help as soon as possible, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Add the `duration` condition after the `productflag` condition.

`CASE` statement  evaluates `input_expression = when_expression` for each `WHEN` clause in the Order specified.

```
UPDATE loans 
SET    description = 
       CASE 
              WHEN productflag = 'p' THEN 'applied for vehical loan ' 
              WHEN productflag = 'gold' THEN 'applied for gold loan' 
              WHEN duration = 'half' THEN 'applied for half year' 
              WHEN duration = 'Quarter' THEN 'applied for Quarter year loan'
             ...
```

Comment: hey Pradeep ,thanks a lot for answering my query...But i think i had tried this and was getting output based on only one condition and not for second....i will check once again tomorrow

Comment: Hii all ,can someone help please ??? i checked on server and it's applying only one condition at a time.I am getting output in which DESCRIPTION has been updated according to Productflag and not Duration.Could anyone tell me how to write a query so that i can get my table updated on the basis of Both Productflag as well as Duration conditions ..at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

From the question I understand, above answer of PrDK is correct (https://stackoverflow.com/a/40203237/4689372).

Seen your output, bit weird one I should say :). Please test with below code.

```
UPDATE LOANS 
SET DESCRIPTION = 
CASE 
    WHEN Duration = 'Quarterly' AND ProductFlag IN ('P','GOLD') THEN 'applied for Quarter year loan'
    WHEN Duration = 'Annual' AND ProductFlag IN ('GOLD') THEN 'applied for ANNUAL loan'
    WHEN Duration = 'Half' THEN 'applied for half year'
    WHEN ProductFlag NOT IN ('P','GOLD') THEN 'APPLIED FOR ' + ProductFlag + 'LOAN'
END
```

Comment: i Agree with you that its a weird output...but the case is here i have formed this table as an example...in actual there is a huge ammount of date on a server.I can surely say that there are around 50 different productflags and Instead of column 'DURATION' there is a column named 'BASEL' which contains 40 different BASELS. so, is there any way we can simply right CASE WHEN THEN for both PRODUCTFLAG and BASEL separately so that i dont need to write number of Combinations in the condition

Comment: Would you please provide the solution you given to this problem? How you implemented it? Thanks.

Comment: i did not found any way by which we can update a single column twice in a single query based on multiple conditions for 2 different columns of that same table. I just updated it twice in 2 different queries.